# Update JSON object after user specified date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, morris.js, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to dynamically update a series of charts based on a user selected date range.  I'm using morris.js to create the charts which are supplied data via a JSON file.  What I'd like to do is initially display the last 7 days worth of data on the charts, then if the user changes the date range I'd like the charts to refresh per the users request.

Here's my chart element:

```
<div id="morrisline" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

All of my charts are contained within a seperate charts.js file:

```
Morris.Bar({
                element: 'barchart',
                axes: true,
                data: Object.keys(json.bar).map(function(key) {return json.bar[key]}),
                xkey: 'x',
                ykeys: ['a', 'b']
            });
```

Here's a sample of the JSON "bar" element -- I don't believe my current format of formatting the date is ideal. I'm open to suggestions since I have control to change the format.:

```
{
    "bar1": {
        "x": "1/1/2014",
        "a": "9",
        "b": "6"
    },
    "bar2": {
        "x": "1/2/2014",
        "a": "5",
        "b": "7"
    },
    "bar3": {
        "x": "1/3/2014",
        "a": "8",
        "b": "9"
    },
    "bar4": {
        "x": "1/4/2014",
        "a": "7",
        "b": "9"
    }
}
```

Here's the daterange callback -- I'm not sure how to exactly update my data element of the chart once the callback has fired.

```
$(document).ready(function() {var cb = function(start, end) {
                    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
```

EDIT: Here's the call to get the JSON data:

```
(function ($, window, undefined) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $.getJSON( "js/data.json", function( json ) {
        //console.log(Object.keys(json.line).map(function(key) {return json.line[key]}));

        if (typeof Morris != 'undefined') {

            //Bar chart
           Morris.Bar({
                element: 'barchart',
                axes: true,
                data: Object.keys(json.bar).map(function(key) {return json.bar[key]}),
                resize: true,
                xkey: 'x',
                ykeys: ['a', 'b']
            });
        }      
    });
    });
})(jQuery, window);
```

Comment: This is a good practice for jquery ui datepicker. You could query your data from the date picker var, and just run a function(ajax call) from within the datepickers function. It would be seamless and probably lighter weight than what you currently have.

Comment: I have to apologize for my lack of knowledge in this area.  Do you think you might be able to provide an example of this?

Comment: are you using ajax to get your json, or is there a json var?

Comment: dont feel bad, json is not a strong point for me

Comment: trying to build a test platform

Comment: See edited post above for the getJSON call.